# VB silverlight for windows phone "System.IO"

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, windows-phone-7.1

hello i am having an error :
"Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.File.Exists(System.String)"

i have to note that this line is having an external url

`If File.Exists("http://www.demo.com/demo.xml") Then
blah
end if`

during my first try it worked but now it seems bugy :S
it does not make sense !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you should be making a web request (e.g. with `WebClient`) instead.

You're using `File.Exists` and passing it a URL. `File.Exists` is meant to be for *file system* paths. In fact, you're not meant to call `File.Exists` at all on Windows Phone 7. When in doubt, consult [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> This member has a SecurityCriticalAttribute attribute on Silverlight for Windows Phone, because the attribute was present in Silverlight 3. This attribute restricts this member to internal use. Application code that uses this member throws a MethodAccessException.